# i want to programmatically get a facebook graph api token

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, htmlunit

I am trying to programmatically get a facebook graph api token 
so far i have used scibe to get the authorazation url and the code is 
:

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                                      .provider(FacebookApi.class)
                                      .apiKey(apiKey)
                                      .apiSecret(apiSecret)
                                      .callback("callbackurl")
                                      .build();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("=== " + NETWORK_NAME + "'s OAuth Workflow ===");
        System.out.println();

        // Obtain the Authorization URL
        System.out.println("Fetching the Authorization URL...");
        String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(EMPTY_TOKEN);
        System.out.println("Got the Authorization URL!");
        System.out.println("Now go and authorize Scribe here:");
        System.out.println(authorizationUrl);
```

the problem is that after that i cannot get the redirect url that contains the code .For tha perpose i use htmlunit a headless browser 
and the code is :

```
HtmlUnitDriver Browser_Session= new HtmlUnitDriver();
        Browser_Session.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        Browser_Session.navigate().to(authorizationUrl);
        System.out.println(Browser_Session.getCurrentUrl()); //This fetches the current re-directed URL.
```

and the response is [THIS URL](https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXX&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.2%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%26client_id%3D1506890296246822%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=page)

instead of

http://www.Redirecturl.com/?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

if i do this manualy eg. copy paste the authorazation url
 then the broser redirect to the correct page!!

Comment: which token do you need? you can´t generate a user token without user interaction, obviously. that would be weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i do this manualy eg. copy paste the authorazation url then the broser redirect to the correct page!!

That's the point.

Automated Facebook auth defeats the purpose of Facebook Auth.

It is designed to be manual, user initiated.